# How to do a for loop with if statement in shell script?

Tags: shell

What is wrong about this code? The if condtion should be correct https://www.educba.com/if-condition-in-shell-script/

```
for file in *; do
    if [$file -ne someFilename]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can run your code through [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch syntax errors.

Comment: Exactly what happened when you tried to run the code? How is that different from what you wanted to happen?

Comment: I want the code to print all filenames to shell except one. Afterwards I want to move them to that one I omit. I am just testing it with echo.

Comment: Ah I need to use != instead of -ne